# Push forward is smooth for jet bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I was reading M,Golubitsky & V.Guillemin's book Stable Mappings and Their Singularities ,in theorem 2.7 (page 40),needs to prove  the following fact:

If $h: Y \rightarrow Z$ is smooth, then $h_{*}: J^{k}(X, Y) \rightarrow J^{k}(X, Z)$ is smooth. If $g: X \rightarrow Y$ is a diffeomorphism, then $g^{*}: J^{k}(Y, Z) \rightarrow J^{k}(X, Z)$ is a diffeomorphism.

The book says it follows from the construction of a smooth structure on $J^k(X,Y)$.I try to prove it in detail taking the push forward for example,that is to show under the coordinate chart,The push forward is smooth.I don't know how to write it clear.

Comment: It basically reduces to noting everything appearing in [Faà di Bruno's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula) is smooth.

Comment: the rough idea to prove this map is smooth may as follows,first smoothness is some local property if we can prove the Euclidean case then diffeomorphic back using chart map gets the desired result。

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood what you said,my bad,when we consider the Euclidean case,the component is given exactly in the form of Faà di Bruno's formula .@user10354138